# Why i can't click this button on selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python, selenium, request

I cannot click some buttons in the router interface. I was only able to click through using pyautogui. But this method is not functional. How can I click this button on Selenium? I will use this code to reset my ip address.

This is the css code of the place I want to click:

```
<a href="#" class="edit" id="editBtn" title="Düzenle" onclick="editClick('ppp1.1', 'MyISP_PTM_35')"></a>
```

Html Data:
https://mega.nz/file/2XJyEbCR#xBcEtzYh8QFLWTmSfAqll2V-p-SHiaw4wEz1RAWtso0

I tryied all method but not worked.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#editBtn'))).send_keys("\n")
except:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#editBtn'))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#editBtn')))[0].send_keys("\n")
except:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#editBtn')))[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#editBtn')))[0].click()
except:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#editBtn'))).click()
```

[image]

Comment: why not ```By.Id,"editBtn"```

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.Id,"editBtn"))).click()
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'Id'

Comment: All caps. for ID. cannot edit in comment

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"editBtn"))).click()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: :) Thanks but still not work

Comment: Can you run the code outside of the try except block and tell us the error that is returned?

Comment: https://ibb.co/XDbWwfX  , I'm throwing the error code as an image.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('')
link.click()
```

you want to click link,
maybe this example helps you.

Comment: What should I add to this value?   ex: by_link_text('editbtn')

Comment: you should add link text

Comment: I tried but not worked :( this link text: http://192.168.1.1/pages/tabFW/tabFW.html?tabJson=../network/broadband/tab.json&&tabIndex=0#

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I should have used frames.

```
#Selenium
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.interaction import KEY
#Beautiful Soup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html

import time

import pyautogui


def router_reset():
    
    print ("Modem resetleniyor")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Anaconda3/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('http://192.168.1.1/login.cgi')
    
    username = driver.find_element_by_id('AuthName')
    password = driver.find_element_by_id('AuthPassword')
    login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login']/fieldset/ul/li[6]/input")
    
    username.send_keys("admin")
    password.send_keys("turktelekom")
    login.click()
    
    time.sleep(1)
    #Açılan Ekranı Atla Tuşu
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login"]/fieldset/ul/li[3]/input[2]'))).click()
    

    source = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="network"]')))
    #target = driver.find_element_by_id("div2")
    target = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="network"]')))
    # Create the object for Action Chains
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.drag_and_drop(source, target)
    # perform the operation on the element
    actions.click(target)
    actions.perform()

    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#network-broadband > a'))).click()

    time.sleep(2)
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mainFrame"]')))
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#editBtn'))).click()

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > div.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > button:nth-child(2)'))).click()


    time.sleep(60)
    print("Modeme Reset Atıldı, 60sn Bekleme Süresi Başladı.")
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="logoutName"]'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > div.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > button:nth-child(2)'))).click()

router_reset()
```